# Views: get image-field with global php

Tags: views

im using Drupal 7 and views 3.

in a global-php-field i tried to show the image from field_artengalerie_term_bild. But

`print $row->field_artengalerie_term_bild;` shows the nid only. then i tried this:

```
print $data->field_field_artengalerie_term_bild[0]['rendered'];
```

but it doesnt output the image.

With `print_r($data);` i get this:

```
 [vocabulary_machine_name] => artengalerie [field_artengalerie_term_bild] => Array ( ) ) ) ) [field_field_artengalerie_term_bild] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [rendered] => Array ( [#theme] => image_formatter [#item] => Array ( [fid] => 648 [uid] => 1 [filename] => standardbild.jpg [uri] => public://default_images/standardbild_7.jpg [filemime] => image/jpeg [filesize] => 19607 [status] => 1 [timestamp] => 1369566211 [type] => image [field_file_image_alt_text] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => standardbild_7.jpg [format] => [safe_value] => standardbild_7.jpg ) ) ) [field_file_image_title_text] => Array ( ) [image_dimensions] => Array ( [width] => 400 [height] => 266 ) [is_default] => 1 [alt] => [title] => ) [#image_style] => thumbnail [#path] => Array ( [path] => taxonomy/term/118 [options] => Array ( [entity_type] => taxonomy_term [entity] => stdClass Object ( [tid] => 118 [vid] => 10 [name] => hjgjhghg [description] => [format] => [weight] => 0 [vocabulary_machine_name] => artengalerie [field_artengalerie_term_bild] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [fid] => 648 [uid] => 1 [filename] => standardbild.jpg [uri] => public://default_images/standardbild_7.jpg [filemime] => image/jpeg [filesize] => 19607 [status] => 1 [timestamp] => 1369566211 [type] => image [field_file_image_alt_text] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => standardbild_7.jpg [format] => [safe_value] => standardbild_7.jpg ) ) ) [field_file_image_title_text] => Array ( ) [image_dimensions] => Array ( [width] => 400 [height] => 266 ) [is_default] => 1 [alt] => [title] => ) ) ) ) ) ) [#access] => 1 ) [raw] => Array ( [fid] => 648 [uid] => 1 [filename] => standardbild.jpg [uri] => public://default_images/standardbild_7.jpg [filemime] => image/jpeg [filesize] => 19607 [status] => 1 [timestamp] => 1369566211 [type] => image [field_file_image_alt_text] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => standardbild_7.jpg [format] => [safe_value] => standardbild_7.jpg ) ) ) [field_file_image_title_text] => Array ( ) [image_dimensions] => Array ( [width] => 400 [height] => 266 ) [is_default] => 1 [alt] => [title] => ) ) ) )
```

how i have to write my code `print $data->field_field_artengalerie_term_bild[0]['rendered'];`to get the image.

regards

Comment: What Im not understanding is... why cant you just set your views to show this field?

Comment: because i want that this field appears only IF ... is True. Thats why i need php and the global php field

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and very simple solution for it I found just need in output write

```
 print render($data->field_field_artengalerie_term_bild);
```

always my solutions is shortest ;)